# Getting JWT token expired in twilio android client

Tags: android, performance, twilio, twilio-click-to-call, twilio-api

I am trying to set up twilio android client and outgoing call. While executing on [`onStopListening()` method](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/android/devicelistener#onStopListening_Device_) throwing some JWT token expired exception. I need help regarding this. I have changed the server time zone and client time zone as same. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly, I believe you are receiving Error [31025 - JWT token expired](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/errors).

Can you confirm what version of Twilio Client you are using and perhaps update your question with the specific error message you receive?

One thing you can try is to create an error handling function that renews or [generates a new token](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/capability-tokens) in response to the error.

Please let me know what happens when you try that.